# Could not to inspect the dedicated host provisioning process

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I used slcli(softlayer-python command) to create a dedicated host, the command return the order id. And I check the order's status was 'APPROVED'.  But I can not get the host in the result of 'SoftLayer_Account/getDedicatedHosts'.

So I check the billing item and it is 'dedicated_virtual_hosts' rightly. Did SoftLayer API support another approach to inspect the dedicated host provisioned? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dedicated host should be listed when calling to **SoftLayer_Account::getDedicatedHosts** method, or when using the **"slcli dedicatedhost list"** command. I suggest to check your permissions and device access, verify that **"View Virtual Dedicated Host Details"** is checked.

Below are some slcli commands I executed to order and list dedicated hosts.

To order a dedicated host:

```
slcli dedicatedhost create -H slahostname -D example.com -d mex01 -f 56_CORES_X_242_RAM_X_1_4_TB
```

To list dedicated hosts:

```
slcli dedicatedhost list   

:.......:...................:..........:..............:................:............:............:
:   id  :        name       : cpuCount : diskCapacity : memoryCapacity : datacenter : guestCount :
:.......:...................:..........:..............:................:............:............:    
: 11111 :    slahostname    :    56    :     1200     :      242       :   mex01    :     -      :
:.......:...................:..........:..............:................:............:............:
```

Below an example about how to see the details:

```
slcli dedicatedhost detail 11111 

:.................:...........................:
:            name : value                     :
:.................:...........................:
:              id : 11111                     :
:            name : slahostname               :
:       cpu count : 56                        :
: memory capacity : 242                       :
:   disk capacity : 1200                      :
:     create date : 2018-02-01T09:53:46-04:00 :
:     modify date :                           :
:       router id : 333333                    :
: router hostname : bcr01a.mex01              :
:           owner : owner001                  :
:     guest count : 0                         :
:      datacenter : mex01                     :
:.................:...........................:
```

Using RestFul the response when calling to **SoftLayer_Account::getDedicatedHosts** should be something like below:

```
GET: 
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getDedicatedHosts

RESPONSE:
    {
        "cpuCount": 56,
        "createDate": "2018-02-01T09:53:46-04:00",
        "diskCapacity": 1200,
        "id": 11111,
        "memoryCapacity": 242,
        "modifyDate": null,
        "name": "slahostname"
    }
```

Also you can use **SoftLayer_Virtual_DedicatedHost::getObject** method:

```
GET:
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_DedicatedHost/11111/getObject
```

Comment: Ok. My 'slcli dedicatedhost list' result is empty.

Comment: did you check your permissions and access?. I recommend to compare the behavior with the Control portal. On my case I used the v5.4 version of softlayer-python client. Also you can open a ticket If the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you. I found maybe I didn't have the 'View Virtual Dedicated Host Details' permission.